# how to obtain proper 'call back URL'

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have installed drupal 7 using MAMP and following [this](http://electriceye.org.uk/node/101) tutorial to configure drupal with oAuth,

While adding consumer I tried call back URL with **domain name** like `http://mastmobilemedia.com/oauth/request_token` which gave `http status 404 error` in browser , when i tried with **IP Address** `http://192.168.1.4/drupal/services/xmlrpc` ( as i found in one of the sample code) i got `page not found error` in browser

so please can anyone help me in knowing what is the proper **call back URL** to be specified ? how to get client side URL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting 404 error because actually there is no page in your site with that url.

In your referenced tutorial the following statements can found as a note:

"
Note: The sample callback URL above is incorrectly shown. The callback URL should be an URL on the client side. When Drupal has authorized the consumer, it will call this URL with the access token as a parameter."

So you have to define a page call back with path as you want. You can define in your custom module.  OR You can give a valid site path as callback url. So When Drupal has authorized the consumer, it will call this URL with the access token as a parameter.

Comment: thanks @anoop from your replay.. im new to drupal so please can you explain  hhow to define menu call back ? and can you provide example valid site path?

Comment: Valid site path means, any existing urls in your site eg: http://mastmobilemedia.com/mobileoperators.html . The url entered by you is http://mastmobilemedia.com/oauth/request_token which is actually not exist. Instead you can give url that exist. You can create a page for this and its url can used or you can define a custom page call back .

Comment: i tried with above URL as you have mentioned i din get anything yet